# I want to set the audio loop automatically

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I got the audio loop source and I want to fix it.
Currently it starts at 0 seconds when it starts.
As you adjust the slider, the section starts to repeat.
For example, start 3 seconds, end 10 seconds -> 3 seconds to 10 seconds are repeated.
What I want is to repeat the default value of 3 to 10 seconds without adjusting the slider.

I've been wandering for days on this issue.
Somebody help me.

This is the original source.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/loopStart)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>decodeAudioData example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>decodeAudioData example</h1>

    <button class="play">Play</button>
    <button class="stop">Stop</button>

    <h2>Set playback rate</h2>
    <input class="playback-rate-control" type="range" min="0.25" max="3" step="0.05" value="1">
    <span class="playback-rate-value">1.0</span>

    <h2>Set loop start and loop end</h2>
    <input class="loopstart-control" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="0">
    <span class="loopstart-value">0</span>

    <input class="loopend-control" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="0">
    <span class="loopend-value">0</span>

    <pre></pre>
  </body>
<script>


// define variables

let audioCtx;
let source;
let songLength;

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
const myScript = document.querySelector('script');
const play = document.querySelector('.play');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');

const playbackControl = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-control');
const playbackValue = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-value');
playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopstartControl = document.querySelector('.loopstart-control');
const loopstartValue = document.querySelector('.loopstart-value');
loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopendControl = document.querySelector('.loopend-control');
const loopendValue = document.querySelector('.loopend-value');
loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source

function getData() {
  if(window.webkitAudioContext) {
    audioCtx = new window.webkitAudioContext();
  } else {
    audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
  }

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'viper.mp3', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


  request.onload = function() {
    let audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        myBuffer = buffer;
        songLength = buffer.duration;
        source.buffer = myBuffer;
        source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;

        loopstartControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
        loopendControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.error});

  }

  request.send();
}

// wire up buttons to stop and play audio, and range slider control

play.onclick = function() {
  getData();
  source.start(0);
  play.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  playbackControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopstartControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopendControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
}

stop.onclick = function() {
  source.stop(0);
  play.removeAttribute('disabled');
  playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

playbackControl.oninput = function() {
  source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
  playbackValue.innerHTML = playbackControl.value;
}

loopstartControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopStart = loopstartControl.value;
  loopstartValue.innerHTML = loopstartControl.value;
}

loopendControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopEnd = loopendControl.value;
  loopendValue.innerHTML = loopendControl.value;
}


// dump script to pre element

pre.innerHTML = myScript.innerHTML;
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]